# iPhone int parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm working on an iPhone app. I want to parse a series of numbers from a string. However, intValue is acting really really strange.

I have a string with the value 1304287200000.

I then place the intValue of that into an NSInteger, and lo and behold, my integer is for some reason assigned the value of 2147483647.

What gives?

Comment: Try using something bigger then integer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The datatype `int` is a 32bit numeric value, with a range of approximately ±2 billion. 1304287200000 is by a margin outside of that range.

You need to skip `int` for `long long` that is a 64bit type and covers your need. A more human readable and explicit name for the 64bit type is `int64_t`.

Comment: Thanks, should have figured that one out, hah :). Have a nice day, and thanks to everyone who contributed!

Answer (score 4):

What you are getting back is `INT32_MAX`, because the parsed value overflows the `int` type. This is explained in the [`NSString` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html). Try `longLongValue` instead, `LLONG_MAX` should be big enough.

Answer (score 2):

`int` is 32-bit, so the maximum value it can hold is 2,147,483,647. Try [`longLongValue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW2) instead.

Comment: `-intValue` doesn't return an `NSInteger` but an `int`. `NSInteger` and `int` can be the same bit size (and in fact on iOS, they are) they need not be on all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Your number exceeding integer limits